# Is the topic of gravitational potential energy convoluted and unnecesary?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, newtonian-gravity, work, potential-energy

If we throw an object upwards from the surface of the Earth, we do some work on it to give it kinetic energy. Now as it travels up, Gravity of the Earth does negative work on it till it loses all the kinetic energy it had and reaches zero velocity, so where does it gain the potential energy to fall back down?

Also, if the object does posses potential energy, why is that energy converted into kinetic energy when it falls? Because the object does no work, it is the Earth that does the work and gives the object kinetic energy, rather it's potential energy.

However, if I do some work on an object in outer space far away from Earth's gravitational field, due to which it gains kinetic energy and reaches Earth's gravitational field, due to which it gains more kinetic energy because of Earth's pull, how did it obtain potential energy to gain more kinetic energy, when I didn't do any work on it to lift it up, rather it was the Earth.

Is the topic of gravitational potential energy unnecessary?

Comment: You know that gravitational potential energy is only zero at an infinite distance right?

Comment: The fact that you gave the object KE in outer space seems irrelevant, since I think you are asking where does the gravitational PE come from to give the object  additional KE. Is that correct?

Comment: In simple non-contact systems like the solar system with 9 bodies, as long as nothing collides, F=GMm/r^2 is all there is to know and implement. It will simulate the solar system day after day. PE, KE, Impulse, Work, even Kepler's laws, are all emergent automatically, ie. if we choose to calculate PE, KE or Kepler's laws and compare, the answer will match automatically. If not, nothing is lost. It's quite stunningly simple.

Comment: The potential energy does not belong to the falling body, it belongs to the pair body-Earth. When the body falls back to Earth, this potential energy is being transformed into kinetic energy of both bodies. But because Earth is so heavy, change in its kinetic energy is negligible and virtually all of energy goes to kinetic energy of the falling body.

Answer (score 4):

> Is the topic of gravitational potential energy unnecessary?

Gravitational potential energy $U_{grav}$ (which is implicitly defined by the work done by gravity $W_{grav}= -\Delta U_{grav}$) is a **great convenience** because it saves you from having to explicitly calculate the line-integral for the work done by gravity along a given path. **So, it's not necessary, assuming you can do the line-integral** (and want to do the line-integral in each problem).
(Gravitational potential energy really is about the system [object and Earth]...
but, for simplicity, we'll treat the earth as immovable.)

> If we throw an object upwards from the surface of the Earth, we do some work on it to give it kinetic energy. Now as it travels up, Gravity of the Earth does negative work on it till it loses all the kinetic energy it had and reaches zero velocity, so where does it gain the potential energy to fall back down?

The object gains the potential energy when (by the definition of potential energy as $W_{grav}= -\Delta U_{grav}$) the Earth's gravitational force doing negative work.

> Also, if the object does posses potential energy, why is that energy converted into kinetic energy when it falls? Because the object does no work, it is the Earth that does the work and gives the object kinetic energy, rather it's potential energy.

The work in the work-energy theorem can be partitioned into two types

\begin{align}
\Delta K 
&= W_{net} \\
&= W_{by\ nonconservative forces} + W_{by\ conservative forces} \\
\Delta K -  W_{by\ conservative forces} 
&= W_{by\ nonconservative forces}\\
\Delta K -  (-\Delta U) &= W_{by\ nonconservative forces}\\
\Delta K + \Delta U &= W_{by\ nonconservative forces}\\
\end{align}

Thus, assuming that $W_{by\ nonconservative forces}=0$ (frictionless, no external work), one can say that the object's kinetic energy is increasing because
"the Earth's gravitational force [a conservative force] is doing positive work" (in the second line) or, alternatively,
"the gravitational potential energy of the object is decreasing" (in the last line).

> However, if I do some work on an object in outer space far away from Earth's gravitational field, due to which it gains kinetic energy and reaches Earth's gravitational field, due to which it gains more kinetic energy because of Earth's pull, how did it obtain potential energy to gain more kinetic energy, when I didn't do any work on it to lift it up, rather it was the Earth.

(As said by the comment that appeared while I was writing this answer) The object always had gravitational potential energy since it is $U_{grav}=-GMm/r$. You just don't notice its change when the object travels a given displacement when it far away from the earth [compared to that same displacement near more familiar terrestrial locations].

Answer (score 0):

> how did it obtain potential energy to gain more kinetic energy, when I
> didn't do any work on it to lift it up, rather it was the Earth.

The gain in kinetic energy came from the positive work done by gravity and the corresponding decrease in the gravitational potential energy of the Earth-object system by the same amount.

Gravitational potential energy, $U$, like all forms of potential energy, is a system property, in this case a property of the Earth-object system, and not a property of the object alone. It is governed by the following general (classical) law of gravity

$$U=\frac{-GMm}{r}\tag{1}$$

Where $U$ is the gravitational potential energy of the Earth-object system, $G$ is the Gravitational Constant, $M$ in this case the mass of the Earth, $m$ the mass of the object and $r$ the distance between their centers.

At distances far from the Earth $U=0$. The increase in kinetic energy $KE$ of the object component of the system due to positive work by gravity as it approaches the earth, equals the decrease in $U$ (it becomes more negative) of the Earth-object system. The original KE you gave the object in outer space is irrelevant with respect to the total *change* in mechanical energy, $\Delta KE +\Delta U$, which is zero. Mechanical energy is conserved.

Likewise, for your thrown object scenario, the initial kinetic energy you gave the object is irrelevant to the *change* in mechanical energy of the Earth-object system. In this case, $U$ is assigned a value of zero on the surface of the Earth (the assignment of zero potential energy being arbitrary) where it possesses the $KE$ you gave it. As it rises its $KE$ decreases while $U$ increases (becomes less negative per equation (1)). Once again the overall total *change* in mechanical energy, $\Delta KE +\Delta U$, is zero so that mechanical energy is conserved.

In summary, the main difference between the two scenarios is the assignment of the location of zero potential. The change (increase) in $KE$ for the space scenario is due to positive work done by gravity making $U$ more negative, whereas in the thrown object scenario the change (decrease) in $KE$ is due to negative work done by gravity making $U$ more positive.

Hope this helps.